# Expanding multi-line snippet adds extra line at the bottom

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, code-snippets

Is there any way to prevent the addition of an extra line below a multi-line snippet in VB.NET?

[image]

(hit tab key to expand snippet...)

[image]

I've double checked that the snippet itself does not have an extra line at the end.  Also, this seems to be VB-specific.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/41b314d4-b448-4eea-be92-c5e29b963ee8/multiline-code-snippet-inserts-extra-blank-line-at-end?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Comment: That's the default behavior I think.

Comment: @PradeepKumar -- Why do you think that?  Any why would that be preferable behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Just close the `]]` after the end of your snipped. The `¿end¿` part sets the caret at this position after inserting the snipped.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
      </SnippetTypes>
      <Title>tryt</Title>
      <Author>[USERNAME]</Author>
      <Description>
      </Description>
      <HelpUrl>
      </HelpUrl>
      <Shortcut>tryt</Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Code Language="vb" Delimiter="¿"><![CDATA[Try

            ¿end¿

        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw New Exception(ex) 'or do some other stuff
        End Try]]></Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```